# Add options to "Move to" (when you right click on a file)

Tags: gnome, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Copy to” and “Move to” context menu options in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166542/copy-to-and-move-to-context-menu-options-in-nautilus)

In Gnome (version 2.30.2), when I right click on a file, one of the options is "Move to -> [Home folder, Desktop]". Is it possible to add other directories to the list of options?

The only information I've been able to find is this:

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24730/

From that I get the impression that it is not possible.