# What are some useful keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to learn some useful keyboard shortcuts. I have become a ninja of keyboard shortcuts in Windows.

Any must-have tips for Ubuntu?

Feel free to include Ubuntu defaults or custom ones you have found useful!

Comment: The answers section has become a collection of community wikis. Why can't people jut use one community wiki and add to it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set up whatever keyboard shortcuts you want through System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. This will also tell you the current shortcuts.

Personally, I [activate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/enable-ctrl-alt-backspace-in-ubuntukubuntu-10-04lucid-lynx.html) to restart the x server, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> as the `xkill` command so I can click on non-responding window to kill it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to open the system monitor (a la Windows) instead of bringing up the shutdown prompt.

There is also a whole load of keyboard shortcuts set by compiz, which can be 
edited using `compizconfig-settings-manager1` (installable from repositories).

I find keyboard shortcuts to be a personal preference and we are lucky that Linux is so customisable as to allow whatever configuration we want.

Answer (score 13):

There's a fairly substantial list on the Ubuntu community wiki.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts

Answer (score 9):

When I found out about <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse 1</kbd> on an open Window. I went nuts moving windows is easy now.

I also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>Left</kbd>|<kbd>Right</kbd>) for switching workspaces.

Lastly I find myself using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> which is the default binding for [Gnome Do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Do) which I love.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is very handy for starting programs, it has auto-completion and prevents you from clicking though the menus.

Comment: Not being able to Alt-drag windows to move them is my most frequent annoyance when I'm using Windows.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that Alt-drag lets you reposition a window in a very free and easy way.  +1

Comment: I usually use super+left/right for switching workspaces super+up for workspace picker and super+down to unfold the desktop cube to see. Makes for really efficient desktop switching.

Comment: I wonder if I'm the only one who re-binds Alt-F2 to "Run a Terminal" .  I figure if I'm going to type something, I must be about to do something interesting, so I might as well have gnome-terminal or another terminal handy.

Comment: @jgbelacqua That's not a bad idea. I usually use Synapse or Gnome-Do so Super + Space gets me everywhere I need to go - including the terminal.

Answer (score 7):

In Nautilus, you can have an extra pane by pressing `F3`. You get a Norton Commander kind of look.

(I learned this here: [Add options to "Move to" (when you right click on a file)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674/add-options-to-move-to-when-you-right-click-on-a-file).)

Comment: Cool! Never know this.

Comment: That one *is* nice. A lot better than opening two nautilus windows >.<

Answer (score 4):

ctrl+alt+l(lock) to lock your desktop.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> : launch applications menu, probably the most used keyword combination in my laptop.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> : Jump to home folder.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> : Show file/folder properties.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> : Launch "run application" dialog box.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> : Close Window.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> : Go back/forward while navigation directories in nautilus.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> :  Go up/down while navigating directories in nautilus.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> : Browse through windows.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> : Permanently delete files, no backing up in trash folder.

<kbd>F2</kbd> : Rename File/Folder.

<kbd>F3</kbd> : Enable split view in nautilus.

<kbd>F8</kbd> : Show/hide nautilus menubar.

<kbd>F9</kbd> : Toggle nautilus side-pane.

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> : "Shift switcher", need to enable it in CCSM.

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> : Inverts all the colors.

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A or W</kbd> : Arrange windows in a nice panel like appearance(Need Compiz).

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> : View/Edit full location path.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> : Select all.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> : New window.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> : New folder.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> : Show/hide hidden files.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> : Lock Screen.

From http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/08/20-useful-ubuntugnome-keyboard.html

Answer (score 4):

If your system has become complete unresponsive to where even hitting CTRL+ALT+F1 doesn't give you a terminal, it is possible to still gracefully stop your machine and reboot.

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> : Raw keyboard mode

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> : Sync the disk

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> : Terminate all processes

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> : Kill remaining process

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> : Remount all filesystems as read only

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> : Reboot

(Another way to kill all processes: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>)

Comment: now I just need to remember alt-sysreq-rseiub next time my system locks bad.

Comment: I've always used R E I S U B instead.   Makes since to me to sync the disks only after killing processes.

Comment: To correct order is REISUB - notice that's BUSIER from right to left.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: Close Window/Tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>: Quit Application

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>: Open Run Application

<kbd>SuperKey</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>: Runs Gnome-Do if installed (Very Cool App)

Answer (score 3):

Once you get Compiz Fusion installed there are a ton of nifty keyboard shortcuts. It's like Exposé on Mac OS X, but even more powerful. I have shortcuts set up to flip between desktops, zoom out/show all windows, show the desktop, launch the console, etc. If you've never used Compiz check it out:

http://wiki.compiz.org/CommonKeyboardShortcuts

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen any shell related shortcuts yet, so here's a few I use a lot in *bash*:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: Search incrementally backwards through command history.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: Exchange characters under and behind the cursor.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: Insert last argument from previous command.

Answer (score 2):

Another few helpful shortcuts while in terminal:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: Copy.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>: Paste.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Left</kbd>: Move to the start of the previous string (for long commands).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Right</kbd>: Move to the next non-alphabet character (eg, '/', '.', '_', '-', etc).

<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> or <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>: Scroll through history of commands.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> is useful for quickly minimizing/restoring all the applications on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Some shortcuts relating to the mouse:

- Alt + Left Mouse Button: move window
- Alt + Middle Mouse Button: resize window
- Super + Middle Mouse Button (drag): zoom to region of screen (Compiz)
- Super + Mouse Wheel: zoom in (Compiz)
- Mouse Wheel when at left or right screen edge: move viewport left or right (Compiz) ([howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8276728&postcount=2))
- Middle Click on scroll bar: scroll immediately

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> Move windows without using the mouse.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> Resize window without using the mouse.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> Minimizes the focused window.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> Toggles maximize.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> Cycle through open windows (bouth windows minimized and not-minimized)

Comment: Also, `Alt + F10` to toggle maximization of the current window.

Answer (score 1):

I like using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrow keys to switch workspaces. I do it a lot. It's fun. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + arrow keys to move windows.

Super-T to open the terminal.

I took a note from the guy above, and made an xkill shortcut--I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is handy as always, but less so, as I just put things on different desktops.

As noted above, using compiz config is wise.

Anyway, there's a reason you're able to customize them all. Get a feel for what you need to do, and how you want to do it. Come on, man, you're using Ubuntu. Go nuts.

Answer (score 1):

These might not be a shortcuts but they do involve using the keyboard: turn on Mouse Keys in Keyboard Preferences and by pressing Fn + [keys that have the same colour as the "Fn" label] you can control the pointer and simulate clicks and click-holds. Keynav is a program in the repositories that is used to control the pointer by using the keyboard to divide a window in half continually. Thus one can click a link with no more than 10 key presses (in the rare case that Vimium/Pentadactyl/Vimperator can't do the job). Long winded it is, but I haven't touched a mouse or trackpad in ages!

Answer (score 0):

Only vaguely on-topic, but I like rebinding the Caps Lock key to the Compose Key. Preferences > Keyboard > Layouts > Options > Compose Key Position, set to caps lock. Try it! Done? Now press Caps Lock, then apostrophe, then e. Voila, e with an accent.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to pop up a main menu at your mouse pointers position.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to execute commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't looked through the emacs tutorial yet, you might want to.  It's got a bunch of keyboard shortcuts that apply to the bash prompt and throughout linux in general.

$ emacs

C-h t

Good luck!

Comment: You can also put:
set -o vi in .bashrc and then you get vim commands at the bash prompt and everywhere else where readline library is used.

Comment: @Sudhanshu, that is just amazing. I consider myself an acolyte in the cult of vi, but I love the key commands. I try to use them quite often, and that little tidbit just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get go on System then Preferences and then Keyboard Shortcuts. You will see the ones that are in use and you can also edit to any key/keys you like or can remember easily...

Comment: i cant remember the defaults so i create some that i can remember easily

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Default keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.10