# Possible to vertically or horizontally tile several open windows?

Tags: 10.10, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

In Ubuntu 10.10, is it possible to vertically or horizontally tile several open windows, just like in Windows? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly duplicate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7798/how-do-i-arrange-my-windows-automatically

Answer (score 1):

You could try `xmonad`.

Install it so:

`sudo apt-get -y install xmonad dwm-tools`

The [blog](http://ubuntu-snippets.blogspot.com/2008/08/xmonad-tiling-window-manager.html) says that dmenu is the application launcher. There was also something called as poison or similar, but I cant recall it.

Comment: Thanks! Mine X window manager is Compiz not Xmonad. Is it possible to horizontally/vertically tile windows in Compiz?

Comment: oh, sorry for that, I havent used a tiling manager. there is one here: http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Grid. But before you do that, you can install `compiz config settings manager` from http://ubuntu-tweak.com/, and play around with the options in that. THere are lots of good tiling option, one even like the window peek on macs.