# How to sort list of terminal windows?

Tags: unity, dock

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I typically have a number of windows open with ssh sessions to other systems, which I label with the system name I'm ssh'd into.  When you right click on the terminal dock icon, you get a list of the windows, but they're ordered in the order they were created.  When there are a large number of them, it can be hard to find the one you want.  Is there a way to sort this list?

Comment: Maybe this helps:  `https://askubuntu.com/questions/7798/how-do-i-arrange-my-windows-automatically`

Comment: No, that's an entirely different issue.  This is regarding the menu and minimized windows.  It may be moot since unity is going away though.