# Which tiling window manager is easiest to install and use inside of GNOME

Tags: window-manager, xmonad

I just tried integrating xmonad with GNOME on Ubuntu 10.04, according to the instructions found here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome#Ubuntu_Karmic

Unfortunately, I was not successful at getting it to work. I'm wondering are there any tiling window managers that are easy to install and use inside of GNOME as a replacement for Metacity or Compiz?

**Update**
I just got xmonad working inside of GNOME. This was a two-step process:

First, execute this line inside of GNOME:

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager xmonad --type string
```

As described here: http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome#Setting_up_Gnome_to_use_Xmonad

Second, and most critically (this was the step I was missing), add the following to ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs:

```
 import XMonad
 import XMonad.Config.Gnome

 main = xmonad gnomeConfig
```

As described here: http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Config-Gnome.html

Answer (score 6):

The only one I can think of that is specifically designed to work within the traditional Gnome setup is [Bluetile](http://www.bluetile.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly comprehensive review of available tiling window managers in [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1844/is-there-a-keyboard-centric-desktop-wm-available/1860#1860); any one supporting EWMH will work with GNOME.

Regarding [XMonad](http://xmonad.org) specifically, I have it running by placing this single line in my `~/.gnomerc` (will work for any window manager, not just *xmonad*):

```
export WINDOW_MANAGER=xmonad
```

No need to create a different session type: just choose the standard GNOME one.  When you want to revert back to metacity/compiz, remove the `WINDOW_MANAGER` line from `~/.gnomerc`.

Answer (score 0):

I found Awesome easy to install and use within Lubuntu 12.04.