# Backspace key for back/forward in a open window

Tags: 13.10, nautilus

I wish to use the Backspace key to go back/forward in a open window just like it is in Windows.

I wish to create a shortcut for "go to previous/next visited location" in an opened window.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's a default action in nautilus. What file manager are you using?

Comment: @maythux: The default changed a while ago (13.04?) to remove the Backspace key shortcut.

Comment: @minerz029 Thanks for info. I haven't checked that

Answer (score 1):

Back: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left Arrow button.

Forward: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right Arrow button.

Take a look at this also:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts
[What are some useful keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242/what-are-some-useful-keyboard-shortcuts)
[What are the new Nautilus (3.6) shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293985/what-are-the-new-nautilus-3-6-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-13-04)