# Add entries to Nautilus' right-click menu (copy, move to arbitrary directories)

Tags: gnome, nautilus, files, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add options to “Move to” (when you right click on a file)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674/add-options-to-move-to-when-you-right-click-on-a-file)

Assume I want to copy a file from `/home/foo/bar/baz` to `/opt/quuz/dir1/option3`. When I try it with Nautilus, first I have to open the correct directory, copy the file, go to the other directory and paste it there. I was thinking of a better way and old KDE3 versions of Konqueror came to mind. It was possible to right-click on a file. The context menu had an option for copying, moving the file to some default directories. Furthermore you could select any directory under `/`. So for the above action one would right click on a file, select `/opt` first, a list of subdirectories will open, select `/opt/quuz` and so on.

Using GNOME there are only two possible values (home and desktop). Is there any way to insert more directories to this context menu in GNOME? Can I copy somehow the behaviour of Konqueror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a long time running idea in Ubuntu Brainstorm http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/1366 and I would like to see this too on Nautilus.