# How to customize "Move to" Directory action structure?

Tags: directory

When i right click on one Directory there is `move to` action, and there is only two options, `Home folder` and `Desktop`

[image]

Is it possible to customize this action to many more or another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been an [idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/1366) on Ubuntu Brainstorm for quite some time now, so in short: no, there is no quick and easy way to change the actual Move To menu. See also this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23796/add-entries-to-nautilus-right-click-menu-copy-move-to-arbitrary-directories) on AskUbuntu.

However, as mentioned, you can use Nautilus scripts to add this functionality. These are scripts that have to be placed in `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` and have to be executable. This way Nautilus will recognize them and add a *Scripts* entry in your right click menu. You could [Google](http://www.google.com/) for some scripts providing what you want.

Alternatively, [Ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) provides some Nautilus scripts (Open Ubuntu Tweak and go to: Personal ▸ Manage Scripts), one of which being *Move To ...* which will pop up a file selection dialog allowing you to pick the destination folder of the selected files. Note that a [similar script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nautilus_Scripts) is provided on the Ubuntu Wiki:

```
#!/bin/bash
# To move selected files to a location

LOCATION=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --title="Select a directory") || exit

IFS=$'\n'
for FILENAME in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
do
    if [ -e "$LOCATION"/"$(basename $FILENAME)" ];then
       zenity --question --title="Conflict While Moving" --text="File ""$LOCATION"/"$(basename $FILENAME)"" already exists. Would you like to replace it?"
       case "$?" in
          1  )  exit 1 ;;
          0  )  mv -f -- "$FILENAME" "$LOCATION" ;;
       esac
    else
       mv -- "$FILENAME" "$LOCATION"
    fi
done
```

(copied here in case the wiki gets updated)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about adding destinations to that menu itself, but [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) can add an alternative move to option which presents a dialog to choose any folder as a destination.

To enable, in Ubuntu Tweak under Manage Scripts drag "Move to..." from the right pane to the left.

As you can see from the screenshot, this is an additional menu entry under a subfolder, so it isn't as seamless integration as would be nice, but it is useful.

[image]