# Why do the "Copy to" and "Move to" context menus in Nautilus only offer "Home" and "Desktop" as options?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions

Why do the **"Copy to"** and **"Move to"** context menu options in Nautilus only include **"Home"** and **"Desktop"** as options?

Is there a way to add other places and even mounted external devices as options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 11.10 onwards

Maybe this might work:

[Nautilus scripts](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Nautilus+Scripts+Pack?content=90330) the bullets state, amongst others:

- Move To... #selected files/folders to ... whereever you want. the script will check if you have write-permissions and if the file already exists
- Copy To...

Pick the 2 scripts from the [download link](http://gnome-look.org/content/download.php?content=90330&id=1&tan=50258347&PHPSESSID=428575ec36f36d43ca75bcc5d32eca57) and just install those just to see if it works. It is fairly old but the way Nautilus works had not changed for as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

## 10.04 to 11.04

You could also try editing the file `/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml`  which has the entries for the Move To menu. Note there are two copies of the Move To menu in that file and I think you would have to edit both.

Answer (score 4):

## 10.04 to 11.04

This already exists in 10.04 from what I can tell. When I navigate to Documents in Nautilus I have a Copy to and Move to context menu which allows me to choose Desktop, Home and other.

If not you could use something like Nautilus Actions Configuration (`sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions`) And setup something like "Move to Home" which would be the following command and parameters:

`/bin/mv`

`%M /home/%U/`

Which would execute the Move command with the full path to all selected files and place them in your Home Folder.

Comment: but how to enable the other panel at 1204

Answer (score 1):

From Debian user using Gnome Desktop Version 2.30.2

1. System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager
2. Download nautilus-actions
3. System > Preferences > Nautilus Actions Configuration
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
5. [Action Tab]

   ```
          [x] Display item in selection context menu

          [ ] Display item in location context menu
   ```

   Context label: _name_of_the_text_you_want_to_be_showed_on_the_context_menu_
6. [Command Tab]

   ```
     Path : /bin/cp
   ```

   Parameters: %M /name/of/the/directory/you/want/to/send/the/file
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + S (to save the action)
8. Open your nautilus and enjoy it!!!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04 this nautilus script works for me, and it displays progress.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`echo -n $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`
DESTINATION=$(zenity --title "Select a folder to move" --file-selection --directory)

qdbus org.gnome.Nautilus /org/gnome/Nautilus org.gnome.Nautilus.FileOperations.CopyFile "file://$FILES" "*" "file://$DESTINATION" ""

exit
```

Comment: what does the script do, It would nice to have details of what it is, and how to use it, how to make and run a nautilus script, ect.

Comment: `zenity`? The OP asked for help on *adding* options, not using another method that works but is not in the copy/move-to lists.